# Raising a python vpn server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to create a vpn server in python, I found this solution: http://voorloopnul.com/blog/a-python-proxy-in-less-than-100-lines-of-code/

but, it works on `Python 2`, and I use `python 3`. Accordingly, I rewrote a bit of code and it turned out like this:

```
import socket
from select import select
import sys
import logging
from this import s



class TcpTee:

    def __init__(self, source_port, destination):
        self.destination = destination

        self.teesock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.teesock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.teesock.bind(('127.0.0.1', source_port))
        self.teesock.listen(200)

        # Linked client/server sockets in both directions
        self.channel = {}

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            inputready, outputready, exceptready = select([self.teesock] + self.channel.keys(), [], [])
            for s in inputready:
                if s == self.teesock:
                    self.on_accept()
                    break

                data = s.recv(4096)
                if not data:
                    self.on_close(s)
                    break

                self.on_recv(s, data)

    def on_accept(self):
        clientsock, clientaddr = self.teesock.accept()
        serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            serversock.connect(self.destination)
        except Exception:
            logging.exception(
                'Could not connect to server %s. Closing connection to client %s' % (self.destination, clientaddr))
            clientsock.close()
        else:
            logging.info("%r has connected", clientaddr)
            self.channel[clientsock] = serversock
            self.channel[serversock] = clientsock

    def on_close(self, sock):
        logging.info("%s has disconnected", s.getpeername())
        othersock = self.channel[sock]

        sock.close()
        othersock.close()

        del self.channel[sock]
        del self.channel[othersock]

    def on_recv(self, sock, data):
        print(data)
        self.channel[sock].send(data)



import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("listen_port", help="The port this process will listen on.", type=int)
parser.add_argument("server_host", help="The remote host to connect to.")
parser.add_argument("server_port", help="The remote port to connect to.", type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)

tee = TcpTee(int(args.listen_port), (args.server_host, int(args.server_port)))
try:
    tee.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logging.info("Ctrl C - Good Bye")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Initially, nothing happened at startup, but after minor edits it started with an error:

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
usage: vpn.py [-h] listen_port server_host server_port
vpn.py: error: the following arguments are required: listen_port, server_host, server_port

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Never faced such how it can be corrected? Or maybe someone already has this implementation

Comment: Ignoring the non-sequitur that is `import this`, how exactly did you start the script? The last 4 lines are the error message produced by `parse_args`, indicating you didn't supply the necessary port and host arguments.

Comment: You can delete that import, by the way: it contributes nothing  (the global name `s` is never used) and is just obscuring the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message

```
usage: vpn.py [-h] listen_port server_host server_port
vpn.py: error: the following arguments are required: listen_port, server_host, server_port

Process finished with exit code 2
```

(ignore the cruft produced by the unnecessary import of `this`) indicates that you didn't run your script with the required arguments. That is, you ran

```
python vpn.py
```

rather than something like

```
python vpn.py 12345 somewhere.com 23456
```

Answer (score 0):

The zen of python appears when you `import this`. The issue with your code, is, therefore, the line:

```
from this import s
```

Comment: This explains the extraneous output, not the actual error raised by `argparse`.

Comment: @chepner this line is highlighted, but even if you delete it, the error remains

Comment: @Apelsin2020, how do you run the python file?

Comment: Highlighted by what? As I said in my comment, the problem appears to be that you aren't running the script with the arguments required by your argument parser. `import this` is just producing a bunch of output that has no impact on the execution of your script.

Comment: @chepner Add a small example of how this should look, I'm a newbie and don't understand it yet